# Query Mongo Collection from Powershell script

Tags: mongodb, powershell, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to run a powershell script which queries the MongoDB collection from pipeline. I am using latest MongoDB driver 2.9.3. I wrote the script as below -

```
$Assem = ("D:\PoweshellMongoDB\Drivers\MongoDB.Bson.dll", "D:\PoweshellMongoDB\Drivers\MongoDB.Driver.dll", "D:\PoweshellMongoDB\Drivers\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll")

$Source = @"
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace MongoDBSample
{
    public static class MongoRepository
    {
        public static void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
                var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("ILP4");
                var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Issues");

                var count = collection.CountDocumentsAsync(new BsonDocument()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type  -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

[MongoDBSample.MongoRepository]::Connect()
```

But when I debug the script I am getting below error -

```
Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At D:\PoweshellMongoDB\PowerMongo.ps1:34 char:1
+ [MongoDBSample.MongoRepository]::Connect()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

I am not sure which reference I am missing. Is there a better way of doing it? Or do I need to update the driver to older version? Please advise.

Comment: Have you looked at this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664028/how-can-i-get-powershell-added-types-to-use-added-types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I created a .NET Framework class library which connects to MongoDB using MongoDB driver 2.3.1. In my pipeline I created setup as - checkout library code from source control, build and publish the dll, from my inline powershell script I am referring this dll and executing it.